# Change die to not stop code from executing

Tags: php, exception, die

In the code below, the code would stop from executing further when Kiyoh would not be reachable. This is not good for production. So I was wondering what the best way would be to replace the `die` function, in a way that the content would execute further -even when Kiyoh would not be reachable-.

The code looks like:

```
        <?php
        // Get KiyOh rating
        $readdir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/kiyoh/';
        $file = 'kiyohdata.dat';

        // Open the file to get existing content
        $kiyohdata = file_get_contents($readdir . $file);

        if( $kiyohdata === false ) { // NOT CACHED

            $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://www.kiyoh.nl/widgetfeed.php?company=YYYYY') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
            $kiyohdata = explode(",", $xml->channel->description);

            if(!empty($kiyohdata)) {
                file_put_contents($readdir . $file, serialize($kiyohdata));
            }

        } else { // IS CACHED
            $kiyohdata = unserialize($kiyohdata);
        }

        $cijfer = str_replace('Average score ', '', $kiyohdata[0]);
        $cijfer = str_replace('.', ',', $cijfer);
        $aantal = str_replace(' Total reviews ', '', $kiyohdata[2]);

        ?>
```

I tried with placing an exception: `throw new Exception("Kiyoh is not available at the moment");`, but the page crashes anyway (Magento 1.9.4.3 webshop).

Comment: Maybe add just a `if (simplexml_load_file(your_file)) { $xml = simplexml_load_file(your_file);  } else { /* print or log your error */ }`

Comment: @Mickaël, your code will load the xml file twice, better to store into a variable as OP has done then check the variable.

Comment: you can put any function there instead of "die" I use  a `mail()` function. or write "logfile" with `file_put_contents`, or if you do not care take the complete part out like starting with or.

Comment: @SyedHussim good point, so maybe just some `file_exists` could do the job

Comment: @Mickaël, file_exists, cannot check for remote file. I believe your answer is correct. I simply meant this. ```$xml = simplexml_load_file(...); if($xml){ ....}```, this way you are not parsing the xml file twice.

Answer (score 0):

this wil send you the error per email

```
    <?php
    $to_email_address = webmaster@example.com

    // Get KiyOh rating
    $readdir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/kiyoh/';
    $file = 'kiyohdata.dat';


    // Open the file to get existing content
    $kiyohdata = file_get_contents($readdir . $file);

    if( $kiyohdata === false ) { // NOT CACHED

        $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://www.kiyoh.nl/widgetfeed.php?company=YYYYY') or mail($to_email_address,"GOOGOO hapened !","Error: Cannot create object");
        $kiyohdata = explode(",", $xml->channel->description);

        if(!empty($kiyohdata)) {
            file_put_contents($readdir . $file, serialize($kiyohdata));
        }

    } else { // IS CACHED
        $kiyohdata = unserialize($kiyohdata);
    }

    $cijfer = str_replace('Average score ', '', $kiyohdata[0]);
    $cijfer = str_replace('.', ',', $cijfer);
    $aantal = str_replace(' Total reviews ', '', $kiyohdata[2]);

    ?>
```

Comment: Hi Max; is there a proper way to handle the error -by means of removing the or operator-, in a way that the page would not crash?

Comment: sure it is better to have good code, but his question as far as I understood it was how to prevent that his script don't stop when other server is offline.